# How to keep looping through a number of rows using the datetime as the counter

Tags: mysql, sql

My question isn't very well put together but below should explain it better

```
SELECT time(starttime) AS time, num_Sold
FROM shop_1
WHERE (CAST( starttime AS date )='2016-06-07' 
AND time(starttime)>'07:00:00' AND zone_name='till_1')
```

This prints out the following

```
    start        No.
    Time        Sold
    07:00:00     0
    07:05:00     0
    07:10:00     0
    07:15:00     1
    07:20:00     2
    07:25:00     9
    07:30:00     8
    07:35:00     8
    07:40:00     4
    07:45:00     1
    07:50:00    10
    07:55:00    10
    08:00:00    19
```

Now I want to sum the No. sold in half hour blocks so from 7:00:00 to 7:29:59(7.25 will be the starttime for the 5 min period to 7:30). How can i iterate through the half hour blocks.

So I want a result

```
    07:00:00     12
    07:30:00     41
    ....
```

It can either be 1/2 hour starting 07:00 or 1/2 hour ending 07:30

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how can you trunc the date every 5 minutes.

```
select trunc(TO_DATE('07/06/2016 10:22:05', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), 'mi')
  - mod(EXTRACT(minute FROM cast(TO_DATE('07/06/2016 10:22:05', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') as timestamp)), 5) / (24 * 60)
    from dual;
```

Better you do a "trunc_minut_function" with this SQL and then use GROUP BY with a SUM in your num_Sold.

something like

```
select trunc_minut_function(starttime), SUM(num_Sold) .....
GROUP BY trunc_minut_function(starttime)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how to implement the `trunc_minut_function` function?